# Unable to access access data within returned Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to set up a unit test for awhile now and decided to start from scratch and follow the Angular2 documentation found here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#live-examples

To attempt to create my unit tests, it fetches the data but I am unable to access it properly within my test.

My service returns type

```
Observable<Review[]>
```

and whenever I got to use any of it within my test it states it is undefined.

```
  it('should have expected the mock local data', async(inject([], () => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(response));

    service.getReviewById(1).toPromise().then(reviewData => {
       expect(reviewData.length).toBe(mockReviews.length,
          'should have expected no. of reviews');
      });
```

My data object I am using for the mockup is:

```
const mockReviews = [ {Id: 1, Title: "Test", Description: "Testing"}];
```

However it states that length is undefined in this scenario.

After poking around on Karma's debugger I found that my Array that is returned is hidden within a parameter "data."

[image]

I tweaked my code to try and compensate and changed

```
expect(reviewData.length).toBe(mockReviews.length,
```

to

```
 expect(reviewData.data.length).toBe(mockReviews.length,
```

But now I receive an intellisense and a compilation error. What am I missing?

Comment: Be sure to return the promise - if you omit this return statement, your test will complete before fetchData completes.

Comment: Show complete code